# how to hide specific table row with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm displaying some data in a table and for each row,but some row hide on click hide button.
HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered event-table">
            <thead class="bg-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scoppe="col">状態</th>
                    <th scoppe="col">学生名</th>
                    <th scoppe="col">大学</th>
                    <th scoppe="col"></th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <% @allname = [] %>
                     <% @event_student.each do |t| %>                       
                    <tr id="pp">
                        <td><%= hidden_field_tag "event_student_ids[]", t.id %>
                            <%= f.radio_button :status, 1,:name=>"status"+t.id.to_s,  checked: t.status == 1? true : false %>参加

                            <%= f.radio_button :status, 0,:name=>"status"+t.id.to_s,  checked: t.status == 0? true : false %> 不参加</td>
                            <% @allname += ["status"+t.id.to_s]  %>
                        <td><%= link_to t.student.full_name, students_path, method: :get %></td>
                        <td><%= t.student.school_name %></td>
                        <td><%= f.submit "delete", :class=> "btn btn-secondary ",:style=>"width:100px", :id=>"hide_delete" %> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <% end %>

                </tbody>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

I tried using jQuery like so, but with no results:

```
$(document).on('click','#hide_delete',function(){
// $(this).closest('table');
$("#pp").hide();
// var id = $("#hide_id").val();
alert('id');
```

Comment: use `$(this).parents('tr').hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could easily be done with the help of a button in each row of the table (I've created a simple table of my own because yours wasn't reproducible). When you click the button the JQuery gets activated and finds the closest `tr` (table row) and hides it.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.hide_row', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').hide()
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.hide_row {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="hide_row">Hide</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="hide_row">Hide</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="hide_row">Hide</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="hide_row">Hide</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="hide_row">Hide</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="hide_row">Hide</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```